# Training the adjacency matrix(weights) as a learnable parameter for graph classification using PyG

Tags: graph, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I am trying to implement Graph CNN for a video data set (using PyG)where the adjacency matrix is based on the inverse Euclidean distance between the transformed features of the objects in a particular frame. Specifically, I have implemented the following:

```
def calculate_inverse_distances(features):
in_channel = 256
linear_layer = nn.Linear(in_channel, in_channel, bias=False)
linear_layer.to(features.device)
transformed_features = linear_layer(features)
transformed_features = transformed_features.detach()
num_features = transformed_features.shape[0]
inverse_distances = torch.zeros((num_features, num_features))
for i in range(num_features):
    for j in range(num_features):
        if i == j:
            continue
        # Calculate the Euclidean distance between feature vectors i and j
        distance = torch.dist(transformed_features[i], transformed_features[j],p=2)
        
        # Avoid division by zero by adding a small epsilon value
        epsilon = 1e-6
        inverse_distances[i, j] = 1.0 / (distance + epsilon)
        inverse_distances[j, i] = inverse_distances[i, j]  # Since distance(i, j) == distance(j, i)
row_sums = inverse_distances.sum(dim=1, keepdim=True)
normalized_inverse_distances = inverse_distances / row_sums
normalized_inverse_distances = F.softmax(inverse_distances, dim=1)
return inverse_distances
```

As you can see, I have applied a linear transformation to the feature vectors using nn.Linear and the weights of this layer are learnable parameters. I have used this adjacency matrix to create a data object. However, I am not sure if I can indeed treat a learnable parameter as a data object in PyG.
Specifically, I have done the following:

```
inverse_dists = calculate_inverse_distances(frame_window_features)
edge_index = inverse_dists.nonzero().t()
edge_weight = inverse_dists[edge_index[0], edge_index[1]]
edge_weight.requires_grad = True
data = Data(frame_window_features, edge_index=edge_index, edge_weight = edge_weight, y =labels)
```

My concerns regarding my approach are as follows:

1. Can the above approach indeed learn the adjacency matrix weights without additional manipulation or do I have to set the edge weights as Parameters separately? If not, that what would be an appropriate way to achieve my objective?
2. Since I intend to do batch-wise graph classification, with each graph having a variable number of nodes, can I treat learnable parameters (weights of the nn.Linear layer) as a data object?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This approach seems confusing. Where does the linear layer come from? Where is it being trained? What are your labels and where do they come from?

I would start by looking at more standard link prediction examples in the PyG library

Comment: HI @Karl, here are my responses to your questions:
1. The linear layers are the transformations of the feature vectors (which are extracted by training a state-of-the-art 3D CNN model and applying ROIAlign for each of the objects detected in a given frame)
2. The labels correspond to the annotated actions for each of the video clips.

Comment: I think more the point is unless the linear transformation is a specific pre-trained linear transformation, it doesn't make sense to have it as a preprocessing step, it should be trained inline with the model. It also doesn't make sense to refer to the adjacency matrix as a "learnable parameter" - the learnable parameters are in the linear layer. It also doesn't make sense to call `edge_weight.requires_grad = True` after the edge weights are computed. It's not clear why you are using a random linear layer as a preprocessing step instead of incorporating it into the model

Comment: Hi @Karl thank you again for your input. I think I understand what you are getting at. Accordingly I have modified the code so that the linear transformation is done within the model and have removed  ```edge_weight.requires_grad = True ``` like you suggested. However, I called the same so as to make sure that the weights of the adjacency matrix are updated and learned by back propagation. But I assume that since  ```nn.Layer ``` is already used and trained with the model. Does this make sense?